# Switching between scenes with buttons

Tags: java, class, button, processing

I am working on a point and click game and would like to switch between scenes with some buttons. I already made all the scenes which are in separate classes as well as the button class. The button class contains two methods one for setting the button and the other for getting the button. Each of the scenes contains two methods as well, one for loading the background image and the other for loading all the functionality of the scene like buttons, spots and signs.

```
class Button {
    Button() { }
        void setButton( float plX, float pmX, float plY, float pmY, float iX, float iY) {
            this.poslX= plX;
            this.posmX = pmX;
            this.poslY = plY;
            this.posmY = pmY;
            this.imgX = iX;
            this.imgY = iY;
          }


       boolean getButton() {
          if(mouseX > plX && mouseX < pmX && mouseY > plY && mouseY < pmY) {
            image(img, pX, pY);
            if(mousePressed) {
              click = true;
            }
          }
          else {
            image(imgH, pX, pY);
            clicked = false;
          }
          return clicked;
      }
}
```

I call all the buttons like this in a method called mainScene().

```
class SceneOne {
       SceneOne() { // some images go here }

void mainScene() {
       button.setClickableArea(1125, 1125 + 164, 60, 60 + 165, 1125, 60);
       button.getClickableArea();

       button.setClickableArea(1125, 1125 + 164, 500, 500 + 165, 1125, 500);
       button.getClickableArea();
      }
}
```

Also i have a Stages class which should contain all the scenes as well as the switching logic. I was planning only to put one method in draw() called gameStart(). The question is how do i make the buttons switch to a particular scene?

Thanks

Comment: Use an MouseListener. That combined with a MouseMotionListener on the component that draws your buttons will give you all the info you need about what the mouse is doing.

Comment: Yes, you create an ActionListener and attach it to the button.
Here are the docs.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

Comment: Can you post some code so i can see how it works? This is not really java, however processing is based on java. I have the button class but i don't know how to pass a method so when the button is clicked, it would trigger that scene/method. Also mousePressed does exactly what it says.

Comment: I suspect that the first two commenters aren't familiar with processing, but I could be wrong-- it is rare to have to resort to ActionListeners in processing. Could you have a state variable that the button sets that stores which scene is currently selected, and then in `draw()` you could check the value of that variable to run the appropriate drawing code?

Comment: I think so too :), and thank you i solved it the way you suggested. It took me some time to figure it out but it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Processing language has built-in functions for mouse listeners, so you need add something like this to you code. (`scene` should be global bool variable)

```
void mousePressed() {
  if(button.getButton()) { 
    //here you somehow store information which scene you want to draw ... e.g.
    scene = !scene;
  } 
}
```

and in you `draw()` or `gameStart()` function switch between them

```
draw() {
  if(scene){
    //draw first scene
  }else{
    //draw second scene
  }
}
```